# IONIC 1 - Scroll a list and before the scroll stops tap an item or swipe it The item selected is not the one you tapped / swiped

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

**I am getting this issue with ionic1**

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local: Local version 3.9.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.16
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v5.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002

**If I remove overflow-scroll="true" attribute from ion-content then it is working fine.**

Scroll a list and before the scroll stops tap an item or swipe it The item selected is not the one you tapped / swiped.

I am getting this issue only for iOS for android it is working fine.